# Gremlin Java Using DefaultGraphTraversal Throws Vertex Already Exists

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to use gremlin java to save vertex into TinkerGraph,
I did a test that first save a vertex to graph, then check if this vertex exist, if not, add same vertex.

This works:

```
GraphTraversalSource graph = TinkerGraph.open().traversal();
graph.addV().property(T.id, "1").next();
graph.V("1").fold().coalesce(__.unfold(),__.addV().property(T.id, "1")).next();
```

I saw graph.V() is actually creating a DefaultGraphTraversal with provided
GraphTraversalSource, so i tried to write it in another way:

```
GraphTraversalSource graph = TinkerGraph.open().traversal();
graph.addV().property(T.id, "1").next();
new DefaultGraphTraversal(graph).V("1").fold().coalesce(__.unfold(),__.addV().property(T.id, "1")).next();
```

But Exception thrown:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex with id already exists: 1`

I wonder why it is not same as first way? DefaultGraphTraversal seems should not be directly used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `DefaultGraphTraversal` class is `public` I don't think it is meant for direct use by users. It may have some use for graph providers however which is why it is not more protected by scope. Stick to writing Gremlin to interact with your graph as it will be the [most portable way](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#staying-agnostic) in which you can build your applications. I would also consider sticking to the more common naming conventions for things:

```
Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
g.addV().property(T.id, "1").next();
g.V("1").fold().coalesce(__.unfold(),__.addV().property(T.id, "1")).next();
```

It's become common to one-line `GraphTraversalSource` creation:

```
GraphTraversalSource g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal();
```

but the point is that "graph" is for `Graph` and "g" is for `GraphTraversalSource`.

As for why direct use of `DefaultGraphTraversal` yields an error:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal();
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property(T.id, "1").next();
==>v[1]
gremlin> new DefaultGraphTraversal(g).V("1")
gremlin> new DefaultGraphTraversal(g).V("1").steps[0].isStartStep()
==>false
gremlin> g.V("1").steps[0].isStartStep()
==>true
```

The difference is that the `DefaultGraphTraversal` call to `V()` is not the same as the `GraphTraversalSource` call to `V()`. The former is a [mid-traversal `V()`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graph-step) and latter is a start-step. Always use the `GraphTraversalSource` and "g" to start writing your Gremlin.

Comment: Thx for you explanation! Why a mid-traversal can cause it not recognize existing vertex "1"

Comment: Because there is no traverser in the pipeline to start the traversal. the mid-traversal `V()` isn't given a traverser to trigger it. the pipeline appears empty so it does nothing. That's why I showed the output of `isStartStep()` - a step that is a "start step" does not need a traverser to trigger it...it has the ability to inject traversers to start the pipeline.